# PHP how to Read URL and Modify the contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I want to read a url, like Google, and modify the HTML tag value.

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
echo $homepage;
```

For example, after read google link, I want set the google search box value to 
`hello word`, something like `<input type='text' value='hello world'/>`

Then display the modified page.

How to do this in php, thank you very much

Comment: I mean set google search box value like <input type='text' value='hello world'>

Answer (score 1):

You would need to modify the content of `$homepage` variable. What `file_get_contents` does is store the content of the file as a string.

So you would have to look up the textbox identifier and use a string function to add the value to the textbox.

Afterwards you would echo the modified `$homepage` variable.

Take a look into string functions here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_string.asp

And particularly into this:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr_replace.asp

If you want to see the string of code that you are actually working with put this at the beginning of your file:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');

echo $homepage;
```

Comment: hi but how to save the modified textbox value to variable $homepage

Comment: Please take a look at the revised answer.